# C# Autofac ParameterFilterAttribute hangs when using Task.Run()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, autofac, multitasking

I have 3 classes: `Apple1`, `Apple2`, and `Apple3`. `Apple2` depends on `Apple1` and `Apple3` depends on `Apple2` like follows.

```
public class Apple1
{
}
public class Apple2
{
    public Apple2(Apple1 apple1) {}
}
public class Apple3
{
    public Apple3([Optional] Apple2 apple2) {}
}
```

I register the three into Autofac

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Apple1>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithAttributeFiltering();
builder.RegisterType<Apple2>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithAttributeFiltering();
builder.RegisterType<Apple3>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithAttributeFiltering();
```

The `[Optional]` attribute is my customized attribute inherited from `ParameterFilterAttribute` like the following

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class OptionalAttribute : ParameterFilterAttribute
{
    public override object? ResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            if (context.TryResolve(parameter.ParameterType, out object? instance))
            {
                return instance;
            }
            return null;
        }
        catch (DependencyResolutionException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public override bool CanResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I resolve `Apple3`, as the constructor parameter `Apple2 apple2` is decorated by `[Optional]`, this `OptionalAttribute` snippet works and resolves parameters. It can work as my expectation: return the instance if successful to resolve or return null if failing/faulted.
But once the code in `ResolveParameter` it wrappered with Task.Run(), it will always hang.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class OptionalAttribute : ParameterFilterAttribute
{
    public override object? ResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start task");
                // The below statement never finishes.
                if (context.TryResolve(parameter.ParameterType, out object? instance))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TryResolve: true");
                    return instance;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("TryResolve: false");
                return null;
            }
            catch (DependencyResolutionException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception");
                return null;
            }
        });
        return task.Result;
    }
    public override bool CanResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output will be only

```
Start Task
```

The entire source code is

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using Autofac.Features.AttributeFilters;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Autofac.Issue
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<Apple1>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithAttributeFiltering();
            builder.RegisterType<Apple2>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithAttributeFiltering();
            builder.RegisterType<Apple3>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithAttributeFiltering();
            
            var container = builder.Build();
            container.Resolve<Apple3>();
        }
    }
    public class Apple1
    {
    }
    public class Apple2
    {
        public Apple2(Apple1 apple1)
        {
        }
    }
    public class Apple3
    {
        public Apple3([Optional] Apple2 apple2)
        {
        }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
    public class OptionalAttribute : ParameterFilterAttribute
    {
        public override object? ResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Start task");
                    if (context.TryResolve(parameter.ParameterType, out object? instance))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("TryResolve: true");
                        return instance;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("TryResolve: false");
                    return null;
                }
                catch (DependencyResolutionException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception");
                    return null;
                }
            });
    
            return task.Result;
        }
        public override bool CanResolveParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, IComponentContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

It's like `context.TryResole` has conflicts with `Task.Run()`. Could anyone take a look?

Comment: You are provoking a deadlock. Never call Task.Result. Always await a Task: `return await Task.Run(...);`. Next, make sure you have all exceptions enabled: go to the VS menu *Debug | Windows | Exception Settings* or press *Ctrl+Alt+E* to open the exception settings and make sure the *Common Language Runtime Exceptions* check box is ticked. Then run the debug mode to get the error. You should consider to avoid executing the builder on a background thread. Instead show a splash screen during start up. There is no benefit or reason to launch a background thread while composing the application...

Comment: @BionicCode I have to use `Task.Result` as the base method is not an async method. While I want to implement a timeout mechanism in `ResolveParameter`. I need to wrapper it with `Task.Run` and use `Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(...), task).Result()` to achieve that; Thanks for your comment, I will take a try to enable debugging stuffs.

Comment: Then better don't use the async API at all. As I said before, you should not use threading during bootstrapping the application. The application is not running yet. There is no UI.  Hence, there is nothing to block. It doesn't make sense. Use a System.Threading.Timer to implementa time out. Let the timer set a flag once it elapses. Let your procedure poll on that flag to know when to return prematurely.

Comment: @BionicCode parameter filtering affects resolve time, not registration time. It'll happen when the app is running.

Comment: @TravisIllig Usually you would avoid to create instances on a background thread in a STA model application. Although you are right that resolving occurs on runtime when instances are created dynamically, you would not want this to happen on an "unknown" thread. There are good reasons to avoid asynchronous instantiation. The point is, he should not try to implement his attribute asynchronous or concurrent.

Comment: @BionicCode Agreed, which is what I put in my answer. I just wanted to be clear about when the thread was happening - at resolve time.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't debugged into this (and, honestly, don't have time) but you're likely getting deadlocks because things are registered `InstancePerLifetimeScope`. To ensure a given component is created once-and-only-once per lifetime scope, there is locking the first time something like that is created. And, of course, if that thing has its own dependencies that are also `InstancePerLifetimeScope`, that's going to cause locking down the chain. You're then throwing async operations into the *middle of a resolve* and that's going to be bad news.

**Resolving an object is not an asynchronous operation.** You can resolve *two different things on two different threads from the same lifetime scope*, sure, but you can't resolve *part of a thing on one thread and part of the same thing on a different thread*.

Think of a container resolve more like a constructor. Constructors are not asynchronous, right? Neither should resolve operations be async.

The answer here is to remove the `Task.Run` from the attribute. You won't actually get anything from it, and likely you're actually making the performance *worse* because instead of doing the fast operation of resolving something on the single thread, you're adding the overhead of spawning a new thread and re-joining later.

If you have some sort of factory that creates objects async, then you need to inject the factory into your constructor and call the async factory method yourself in your constructor. Trying to mix the sync and async in a fully synchronous object construction is a recipe for bad times.

Comment: Thanks much Travis. Just curious if I do have a requirement to implement a timeout mechanism in the parameter initialization: return instance if resolving within 5s; null if exception or out of 5s. What's the better way except using the factory in a "lazy" style? Is there any other way else besides "await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(5000))" to limit the execution time for a code snippet?

Comment: Limiting the time of a resolution isn't something Autofac handles. Resolving an object is like calling `new` - it should be fast and atomic. You shouldn't be doing anything that would need to run async or take a lot of time.